# Main.js file in React -native not reflecting in my code

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new in react-native applications.
When i am going to do changes in the Main.js file nothing is reflecting into it.but it works while changes in the index.android.bundle file.

what is the need of main.js file when all is reflecting into index.android.bundle file

I want to know the way to change the file in main.js so that i can be able to check the changes to the project.

Below are the file structure 
android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

(Main.js file structure)
   project/main.js

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to run below command after doind changes in the react js files 
main.js . It will bundle them  to android state

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

Then you need to run :->
command : react-native run-android

All changes will reflect into it directly on index.android.bundle files